# python for loop index

Tags: python, for-loop

i have two function below with two for loops. in the first one i need the index [i] for both inputs a[i] * b[i], while in the second I need it next to output as well as next to matrix[i].

Why, what is the logic behind these indexing reference [i]?

If I do not index matrix with [i] I get this

[image: error]

```
def w_sum(a,b):
      output = 0 
      assert(len(a) == len(b))
    
      for i in range(len(a)):
        output += (a[i] * b[i])
    
      return output


def vec_mat_mul(vector, matrix):
  output = [0, 0, 0]
  assert(len(vector) == len(matrix))

  for i in range(len(vector)):
    output[i] = w_sum(vector, matrix[i])
  
  return output
```

here are the input variables and dependent function w_sum:

```
#dataset at the beginning of a game
toes = [8.5, 9.5, 9.9, 9.0]
wlrec = [0.65, 0.8, 0.8, 0.9]
nfans = [1.2, 1.3, 0.5, 1.0]

#inserting one input datapoint of each variable
input = [toes[0], wlrec[0], nfans[0]]

#defining weights
weights = [[0.1, 0.2, -0.1],
           [-0.1, 0.1, 0.9],
           [0.1, .04, 0.1]]
```

Might be a very mundane question but I need to get the logic to move on.

Thanks!

Comment: Where are you calling `vec_mat_mul`?

Comment: If you want to multiply matrices, I suggest you use numpy arrays rather than Python lists

Comment: Are you asking what indexing a list does?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I want to create it without numpy first to understand the logic. I am calling vec_mat_mul here: 

`def nn_mul_in_out(input, weights):
  pred = vec_mat_mul(input,weights)

  return pred

neural_output = nn_mul_in_out(input, weights)

print(neural_output)`

Comment: @interjay no I am asking why i need to refer to [i] in the for loop of the vec_mat_mul function here: `matrix[i]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TLDR;** removing [i] from matrix means you multiplying a list (sequence) of lists with a list of floats, which gives the error message.

I am assuming you are calling `vec_mat_mul(input, weights)`. You are multiplying a 1d vector (list of floats) by a 2d matrix (list of lists).

Now for the line `output[i] = w_sum(vector, matrix[i])`: If you remove the index `[i]` from `matrix`, it means that you are passing a `matrix` as a list of lists.

For the line `output += (a[i] * b[i])` inside `def w_sum(a,b)`: It will perform an element-wise multiplication between floats of the first list and lists of the second list which is undefined, and therefore you will get the error: `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'`. The sequence here is the matrix which is a sequence of lists.

Now for the correct behavior, if you pass `matrix[i]` in `output[i] = w_sum(vector, matrix[i])` it means you are passing only an element of the matrix which is a list of floats, therefore you are doing an element-wise multiplication of a list of floats with another list of floats which is what we expect.

Comment: "it means you are passing only an element of the matrix which is a list of floats, therefore you are doing an element-wise multiplication of a list of floats with a list of floats which is what expected."

thank you so much, this clears is up perfectly in my head!